# flickering android screen once drawing using a loop libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

im drawing a basic grid using a nested for loop (libgdx) but when i test it on android it keeps on flickering i have tried many different ways but still cant get it to stop the flickering.. here is my code

```
public void create() {      

    rend = new ShapeRenderer();
    screenH = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    screenH = (int) (screenH*(0.32));
    System.out.println(screenH);
    screenW = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    screenW = (int) (screenW*(0.322));
    System.out.println(screenW);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    dots = new Rectangle();
    storeV();
```

render method

```
public void render() {      
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1);
    //Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    rend.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    batch.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    rend.rect(100, 100, 200, 200);
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
        for (int j=0;j<4;j++){
            //batch.draw(dot, posx, posy);
            rend.setColor(Color.WHITE);

            rend.rect(posx, posy, 16, 16);
            posx+=screenW;
        }
        posx=0;
        rend.rect(posx, posy, 16, 16);
    //  batch.draw(dot, posx, posy);
        posy+=screenH;
    }
    rend.end();
    batch.begin();

    batch.end();

}
```

as you see i have tried drawing a rectangle and using a texture but both happen to flicker. the rectangle  drawn outside the loop dosent flicker.

and here is my storeV()

```
public void storeV(){

for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
    Xpoints[i]+=screenW*i;
}
for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
    Ypoints[i]+=screenH*i;
}
```

Comment: Two things: 1) Which Android device are you testing on? 2) Could you post full code (eg, on pastebin) that recreates the problem.

Comment: Why did you comment the glClear out? Maybe this was a wrong decision. There seems to be nothing wrong with the shaperenderer. I would look at the code, where you add your screenW and screenH. Maybe it's flickering, because the rect is one frame outside the viewport and next frame in the frame again. Don't forget to reset your posY!

Comment: @Chrise i commented that just trying to see if thats the problem which was quite stupid xp.. the resetting the posy fixed my flickering but when i added the rest of the code im still facing some issues but ill try to figure it.. thanx a lot

Comment: @RodHyde im using galaxy tab 1